# Using TableView.Select with path strings

Tags: vb.net, select, datatable

Using the following:

```
Dim rowArray() As DataRow = ToolsDataSet.FileTable.Select("FullPath Like c:\ENG Vault\Tools\Wakesetter.SLDASM")
```

I am getting the error:

> System.Data.SyntaxErrorException: 'Cannot interpret token ':' at
>   position 16.'

Yet, the path stores fine when I do an insert and store the string with the : and \ characters.

How does one escape the special characters in a path specification for a select?

Edit: I also tried:

```
Dim filePath As String = 'c:\ENG Vault\Tools\Wakesetter.SLDASM'
Dim selText As String = "FullPath Like " & filePath
Dim rowArray() As DataRow = ToolsDataSet.FileTable.Select(selText)
```

Same result.

Comment: I think you need to put the path part (c:\ENG Vault\Tools\Wakesetter.SLDASM) in to single quoutes `'` to denote the search string

Comment: @JayJ - Thanks, tried that already. When I do all the rest of my code turns red (string) and I get the error String constants must end in double quotes.

Comment: Try the line: `Dim rowArray As DataRow() = dt.Select("Fullpath like 'c:\ENG Vault\Tools\Wakesetter.SLDASM'")` Note the brackets after `DataRow`

Comment: @JayV - Thanks (Smacks self in side of head)